# Not found error on wordpress categories and products

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, woocommerce, http-status-code-404

My wordpress site is still accessible (http://thewatch.vn/) but when clicking to categories and products (such as http://thewatch.vn/danh-muc/dong-ho-nam/), it returns Not found error

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /danh-muc/dong-ho-nam/ was not found on this server.

I have searched and it seems to be .htaccess problem. I've tried the .htaccess suggested here http://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

and many other variations, but no luck. More info: this site uses Woocommerce; the Permalink settings are:

> Common Settings: Post name
>
> Product category base: danh-muc
>
> Product permalink base: Custom base (/san-pham)

Comment: WordPress should automatically create the htaccess rewrite rules when you make changes to the permalink setting. Depending on server settings you may have to copy the generated conf across. I'd get WP to regenerate it. Also, do you know if your server has mod_rewrite installed?

Comment: go to the admin panel and check any product permalink first.

Comment: Do you have that name product 'dong-ho-nam' ?

Comment: @dotty yes, ran 'httpd -M' and there's rewrite_module (shared) in the list. "Depending on server settings you may have to copy the generated conf across" <-- in which cases and how?

Comment: @siddhesh yes, it's in Products/Categories

Comment: Is default permalink strucure does work ?

Comment: @siddhesh yes, the products are shown when i switch the "common settings" to Default, though the categories show a blank page (probably the theme template's problem)

Comment: I will come tommorow I have to go to the bed now.

Comment: do you make any edits to functions.php or any core code

Comment: @siddhesh no, no changes

Comment: backup your htaccess and try make blank your .htaccess file and also refresh your permalink settings by replacing it.

Comment: @siddhesh i have tried as you said, deleted the .htaccess file, set the permalink settings to default (wp created a almost blank .htaccess file), then reset the wanted settings (wp created the .htaccess with default content), but everything's still the same :(

Comment: can you provide your front site link to see what's the actual issue is 'I am not asking for admin panel just front side'

Comment: @siddhesh you mean the home page? I have already posted it in the question :) http://thewatch.vn/. Btw, I tried the same code on local xampp (the only difference in wp-config, of course, and maybe a little in the DB, but i don't think it's relevant) and the products can be accessed normally.

Comment: your landing page also not working

Comment: does your root directory have readme.html

Comment: I think i am near to the answer but i want to talk to you and clear some mind

Comment: hmm... the landing page doesn't load for you? i still can access my landing page with no problems. Maybe because the network from the server (in my country) to your place is not good? "does your root directory have readme.html" <-- no, currently there isn't

Comment: @siddhesh so have you had any answer yet?

Comment: yes i like to read the previous conversation just wait a minute

Comment: what is the danh-muc category or product? sorry i am unable to understand your language

Comment: @siddhesh danh-muc means "category" in my language. So thewatch.vn/danh-muc/... = thewatch.vn/category/...

Comment: 'dong-ho-nam' is the name of category. ok. but which category product category or wordpress built in category

Comment: Ok just replace your product permalink structure back to the category/product link and ensure that .htaccess is created.

Comment: I have deleted the "product category base" field (it defaults to product-category) and tried all the options in the "Product permalink base" section but none works. The only options that work are the Default for "Common Settings" and "Product permalink base".